# Creating account for Logic Apps in Visual Studio 2019 - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio-2019, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to develop LogicApps with Visual Studio 2019, but getting errors. What could be wrong?

1. I have installed VS2019 and Logic Apps extension
2. I have clicked "Open with Logic Apps Designer"
3. I have Added Account and I can successfully see list of resource groups and select correct one.
4. I click ok, but dialog just empty my account selections or it gives simple error:

ERROR:
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.